# Rails 3: role_mask won't save - WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, devise, cancan

I'm using the code from Railscasts 189 to implement roles with Devise so I can use Cancan.  However the roles are not being saved to the role_mask field.  Relevant code from my user model:

```
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                  :name, :about, :awards, :url, :roles_mask

  ROLES = %w[admin support worker monitor visitor]

  named_scope :with_role, lambda { |role| {:conditions => "roles_mask & #{2**ROLES.index(role.to_s)} > 0"} }

  def roles=(roles)
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.sum
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject { |r| ((roles_mask || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero? }
  end

  def role_symbols
    roles.map(&:to_sym)
  end
```

In the views for user "new" and "edit" I have the following to show checkboxes for the roles:

```
  <p>
  <%= f.label :roles %><br />
  <% for role in User::ROLES %>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[roles][]", role, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
    <%=h role.humanize %><br />
  <% end %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "user[roles][]", "" %>
  </p>
```

When I check the check boxes for a couple of the roles and hit "submit", I get the following flash:
1 error prohibited this user from being saved:

And I get the following error from the server:
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: roles

I've checked the DB and nothing gets saved in the roles_mask field.  There are lots of questions in Stackoverflow about "can't mass-assign protected attributes" but they don't seem germane to this situation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding :roles to the attr_accessible list like this:

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                  :name, :about, :awards, :url, :roles_mask, :roles
```

Understand completely about the mass-assignment issues before doing this.

Comment: That worked.  Not sure I understand why.  Is it because the "roles=(roles)" and "roles" methods are acting as a setter/getter pair?

Comment: @dleatham http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible